# Prevent from getting Downloading data message using BatchGetSymbols in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, finance

I am using BatchGetSymbols() to download financial data from yahoo.finance. I would like to use the data for an R markdown file, however the downloading message keeps popping up:

```
## Running BatchGetSymbols for:
## tickers = MSFT
## Downloading data for benchmark ticker
## Downloading Data for MSFT from yahoo (1|1) - Boa!
```

That is even though I have switched off messages:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, warning = FALSE, error = FALSE, message = F}
````

I tried invisible() and have looked for options such as quietly = TRUE, but no success so far. Downloading data on many stocks will result in pages of messages before getting to the actual content of the R markdown file.

Any help would be appreciated. Perhaps there is another function that will better fit this purpose.

Comment: Does the chunk option `include=FALSE` solve your issue? From the [**knitr help**](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#text-results): include: (TRUE; logical) whether to include the chunk output in the final output document; if include=FALSE, nothing will be written into the output document, but the code is still evaluated and plot files are generated if there are any plots in the chunk, so you can manually insert figures; note this is the only chunk option that is not cached, i.e., changing it will not invalidate the cache.

Comment: that did it, thanks!